# Disabling watchdog in Raspberry Pi Archlinux ARM

Tags: archlinux, watchdog

Speaking of Watchdog, [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Improving_performance#Watchdogs) archwiki says:

> Many users need this feature due to their system's mission-critical
>   role (i.e. servers), or because of the lack of power reset (i.e.
>   embedded devices). Thus, this feature is required for a good operation
>   in some situations. On the other hand, normal users (i.e. desktop and
>   laptop) do not need this feature and can disable it.

On my laptop I can disable the watchdog in three different ways:

1. `rmmod iTCO_wdt` for temporary effects or writing `blacklist iTCO_wdt` to `/etc/modprobe.d/nowatchdog.conf` for persistent effects.
2. writing 0 to `/proc/sys/kernel/watchdog` or `sysctl -w kernel.nmi_watchdog=0` for temporary effects, or writing `kernel.nmi_watchdog = 0` to `/etc/sysctl.d/nowatchdog.conf` for persistent effects.
3. Appending `nowatchdog` to `/etc/default/grub` if GRUB is used for persistent effects.

---

None of them works for the raspberry pi:

- 1 Doesn't work because the iTCO_wdt is not loaded.
- 2 Fails because there is no `watchdog` or `nmi_watchdog` under `/proc/sys/kernel/`
- 3 Can't work because raspberry pi doesn't use GRUB.

The Output from `wdctl` (executed as root):

```
Device:        /dev/watchdog0
Identity:      Broadcom BCM2835 Watchdog timer [version 0]
Timeout:       15 seconds
Pre-timeout:    0 seconds
Timeleft:      15 seconds
FLAG           DESCRIPTION               STATUS BOOT-STATUS
KEEPALIVEPING  Keep alive ping reply          1           0
MAGICCLOSE     Supports magic close char      0           0
SETTIMEOUT     Set timeout (in seconds)       0           0
```

Is it possible to disable the watchdog feature in Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Archlinux arm?

Comment: To be honest I do not think it’s triggering.  Looking at your output from wdctl, timeout is set to 0 and that normally means the function is off...

Comment: @Andyroo: `Timeout:       15 seconds`

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev But surely you computer is not resetting every 15 seconds?  Running the wdctl in a loop should show the timeleft value dropping from 15 seconds and resetting when it reaches zero WITHOUT a reboot or anything happening to the box

Comment: @Andyroo My Pi does reset 15 seconds after `sudo touch /dev/watchdog`. I haven't tried to activate `watchdogd`, but I'm pretty sure that will work as well. Of course the watchdog is not active from the start: that would lead to a reset loop unless your Pi boots in less than 15 seconds.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev Sorry - I meant to say SETTIMEOUT being 0 not Timeout.  I would expect the machine to reset after your 'touch' command - that sets the timer running.  As nothing will be doing this in normal operations I would leave it as it is.

Comment: @Andyroo SETTIMEOUT is a compile-time binary flag (0 or 1), not a time value. It cannot be changed at runtime at all.

Answer (score 3):

Watchdog is built into the Raspbian kernel using `CONFIG_WATCHDOG=y` in kernel parameters, so `rmmod` is not possible unless you rebuild the kernel. 
`/proc/sys/kernel/watchdog` is not implemented in Raspbian either. I'm not sure about Arch, but judging by your question the situation there is similar.

You don't need GRUB to pass parameters to the kernel: on Raspbian you do this by editing `/boot/cmdline.txt`. Putting `nowatchdog` there should persistently disable the watchdog.

Having said that, the watchdog will not activate until you open `/dev/watchdog`. So unless you run a watchdog daemon which keeps `/dev/watchdog` open, it is effectively inactive and I see no reason to disable it.